# Are threads run on CPU or core?

Tags: multithreading, cpu, cpu-architecture, cpu-cores, hyperthreading

Is a single thread run on a single core or a single CPU?

Also, I have i7. It says I have 4 cores, but 8 threads. Isn't core related with thread in 1-1 proportion? How did it double it?

Comment: Look up hyperthreading.

Comment: see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/runtime_availableprocessors.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A CPU, in this context, is a single physical chip which can be installed separately from other CPUs on the computer (should there be a place for multiple CPUs).

A "core" is a processing element of a CPU that is a distinct piece of hardware from other cores. If a CPU provides more than one core, the expectation is that the cores not only execute independently of each other, but that they do not contend for most resources on the same CPU to do their execution. That is, multiple cores provided by the same CPU are not sharing much of the CPU's hardware.

A "thread" in this context(note: the term "thread" as used in most programming contexts is related but different) is a path of code execution, with its own distinct set of registers. A core provides one or more threads. However, if a CPU core exposes multiple threads (typically only 2), the expectation is that the threads *do* contend with each other for execution resources.

The idea with multi-threaded cores (commonly called hyperthreading) is that cores have lots of execution resources. And a single stream of instructions cannot always saturate all of these resources. So if a core runs instructions from two threads, it can more efficiently use its computational resources.

And sometimes operations just shut a thread down. Memory fetches often can stop a thread in its tracks to wait for the data from RAM. At those times, a second thread on the core will get the core to itself until the data arrives.

Comment: An unambiguous term for the concept in your first paragraph is "socket".  e.g. a 2-socket server might have two multi-core CPUs.  Or, this 12c24t system has two 6c12t processors.  (So two chips with six physical cores, each supporting two logical cores per physical core with SMT).  Hyperthreading is Intel's trade-name for the computer-architecture concept of [SMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_multithreading), but it's more well known so it often gets used like Kleenex or Hoover to describe SMT on other vendors' CPUs.)

Answer (score 3):

It is a common misunderstanding. There are two kind of threads , Software and hardware. While writing multi-threaded programs, You are talking about software threads. While talking about 4 (physical) cores with 8 (logical) HT(Hyper-threaded) cores, you are talking about hardware threads. The number of active software threads could be in 1000's, scheduled in a time-sliced manner by operating system (OS), on limited number of hardware threads.

Answer (score 1):

When Intel’s CPU designers started developing cores that could emulate 2 cores (a trick that sometimes makes better use of the limited cache capacity than a single core could), they decided to appropriate the word “thread” to describe them. They might just as well have chosen “virtual core” instead, but didn’t. They then stuck the word “hyper” in front to, well, I don’t know why. The term Hyperthread is just annoying for the confusion it causes with OS threads, which is a different thing altogether.

Other processors have done this before. The Inmos Transputer could emulate numerous cores, but were commonly thought of as “processes”, though the motivation there had nothing to do with efficient exploitation of a cache (it was intended to support the language we used on them, Occam, which was an implementation of Communicating Sequential Processes, something that is suddenly fashionable again in languages like Go, Rust).

Comment: SMT (such as Hyperthreading) is generally about making better use of *execution* resources, like ALUs and FP execution units, coming closer to keeping them fed with work to do.  Having two threads competing for per-core private caches is usually a bad thing, but often not a showstopper.  (For well-tuned code that doesn't stall a lot on branch mispredicts or cache misses, SMT often doesn't help much.  For a matrix multiply that can already keep both FP pipelines full with a single thread, two threads competing for cache is actually slower because they're tuned to cache sizes.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I was coming at it from the direction that I think Intel used to talk about, maximising the value of having a cache that size in the first place. I.e. if one thread suffered a cache miss, but the cache still contained other data for another thread then the CPU core may as well get on with running the second thread. The notion was that the cache is bigger than most threads would need it to be and they would anyway be branching / missing a lot, so having two hardware threads is more likely to make full use of the cache. As you point out, one's mileage may vary!